# socle of a quotient module

Tags: modules, socle

As the title says, I am interested on the socle of a quotient module. Let $R$ be a ring and $M,N$ two left $R$-modules. If $f: M \rightarrow N$ then $f(socle(M)) \subseteq socle(N)$. In particular, if $N\leq M$ and $\overline{\cdot}:M\rightarrow M/N$ is the canonical projection, then $\overline{socle(M)}\subseteq socle(M/N)$. Are there, in general, (non-trivial) circumstances that would guarantee equality? Under what conditions is $socle(M/N) \cong socle(M)/socle(N)$ true (if at all)?

If it helps, my rings are commutative and artinian.

Comment: You mean $\operatorname{soc}(M/N) = \operatorname{soc}(M)/N$? If so $\operatorname{soc}(M) \not\subseteq N$ is needed for $N \subset M$, at least.

Comment: @orat I am just looking for the socle of $M/N$. The question is meant as it is.

Comment: I see. I just asked because if your question is exactly what you wrote then the first part — $\operatorname{soc}(M)/N \subseteq \operatorname{soc}(M/N)$ — looks almost irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

This answer might be a kind of trivial. But I post anyway because I'm not sure what you mean by non-trivial, mathematically.

*Claim*. If $N$ is a direct summand of $M$ then $\operatorname{soc}(M/N) = \overline{\operatorname{soc}(M)}$.

*Proof*. Let $L$ be a complement of $N$ in $M$. Then
$$ 
\overline{\operatorname{soc}(M)}
= 
\overline{\operatorname{soc}(N \oplus L)}
= 
\overline{\operatorname{soc}(N) \oplus \operatorname{soc}(L)}
\cong
\operatorname{soc}(L)
\cong
\operatorname{soc}(M/N).
$$